# Adding dependencies for use in build.sbt itself

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I'm not asking here how to add library dependencies to an SBT project. I'm asking how to add a library that is to be called from within build.sbt itself (or the files under project/* that will be called from build.sbt). For example, the circe-yaml library for parsing and editing YAML files. How does one add a third-party dependencies to that?

Comment: [**sbt** is recursive](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html), you can add it into `project/build.sbt`.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!